# Does firewalld handle the common attack rules of iptables by default?

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, centos7, firewalld

I'm in the process of migrating servers to CentOS 7 from 6.5 and the most major change appears to be the shift from `iptables` to `firewalld`.  My prior experience with `iptables` tells me that there are a number of common attack vectors that one needs to set up rules to protect against, such as *null packets* or *XMAS packets* or *syn-floods*.  After reading through as much of the documentation of `firewalld` as I can, I haven't been able to figure out whether or not `firewalld` comes with common protection meaures out of the box.

**Does `firewalld` handle all of the common attack protection measures by default that one would have to add to `iptables`?**

I'm guessing it does, but I'd rather not make assumptions when it comes to security.  My evidence of this:

- Rackspace's default CentOS 6.5 `iptables` rule set appears to include a variety of these attack vectors, but their CentOS 7 `firewalld` rule set does not appear to include anything special.
- DigitalOcean's [recommendations for setting up CentOS 6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-basic-ip-tables-configuration-on-centos-6) includes adding several protection measures but their [recommendations for CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/additional-recommended-steps-for-new-centos-7-servers) do not.
- Googling "firewalld null packets" or the like produces no useful results.

My only reason for doubting this is that `firewalld` is too new for "best practices" to be published.  I don't know enough to make this determination myself by actually attacking the firewall.  Any help on this?

Comment: That tutorial for CentOS 6 is crap. It doesn't properly configure the firewall as fully stateful, which if done correctly makes most of their "special" rules unnecessary. A firewalld configured firewall is 100% stateful (unless you add custom rich rules that break it) and doesn't need this junk.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What does it mean for a firewall to be "stateful"? And are you confirming that firewalld handles most common attacks by default?